# Compile-time fold results in error when called with a lambda

Tags: d

I'm trying to `fold` an array at compile time, and store the result in an `enum`. It works just fine when the enum (and call to `fold`) is at module-level, but compilation fails when its both contained within a struct **and** called using a lambda.

Here's a simple example of some failing code:

```
import std.algorithm.iteration;
import std.stdio;

struct Foo
{
    // Version 1 (works)
    //enum x = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!"a * b";

    // Version 2 (works)
    //enum x = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!mult;

    // Version 3 (broken)
    enum x = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!((a, b) => a * b);


    pragma(msg, "x = ", x);
}

// Outside of the struct, it works
enum y = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!((a, b) => a * b);
pragma(msg, "y = ", y);

int mult(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

void main(){}
```

(Versions 1 and 2, which are commented out, compile just fine. It's just Version 3 that has problems.)

Upon compiling, the following error is thrown:

```
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(3690): Error: `this.__lambda2` has no value
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(3690):        while evaluating: `static assert(((int)).length == fun.length)`
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(3697): Error: `this.__lambda2` has no value
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(3718): Error: `this.__lambda2` has no value
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(3636): Error: template instance `broken.Foo.reduce!((a, b) => a * b).reduceImpl!(false, int[], int)` error instantiating
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d(4086):        instantiated from here: `reduce!(int[])`
.\broken.d(13):        instantiated from here: `fold!(int[])`
x = .\broken.d(13): Error: CTFE failed because of previous errors in `fold`
.\broken.d(16):        while evaluating `pragma(msg, x)`
y = 6
Failed: ["C:\\D\\dmd2\\windows\\bin\\dmd.exe", "-v", "-o-", ".\\broken.d", "-I."]
```

I've tried looking at the source code mentioned in the error, but the concepts it uses are beyond my current level of knowledge of D.

I initially assumed that lambdas might not work properly at compile-time, but `enum y` evaluates correctly, so I'm guessing it's not that...

I'm using DMD v2.086.1, but had the same problem using LDC 1.16.0 and 1.14.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the compiler not being very good at figuring out if a lambda needs access to its context. If you'd written something like this:

```
struct S {
    int n;
    int fun() {
        import std.algorithm.iteration : fold;
        return [1,2,3].fold!((a,b) => a*b*n);
    }
}
```

It should be clear that the lambda above needs access to `n` in the struct. In the same way, the compiler errs on the side of caution for `enum x = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!((a, b) => a * b);`, and assumes there's some state inside `Foo` that will affect the result of the calculation. Filed this as [issue 20077](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20077).

You have already found some workarounds, and there's another worth mentioning - adding argument types to the lambda:

```
enum x = [ 1, 2, 3 ].fold!((int a, int b) => a * b);
```

This way, the compiler figures out what info the lambda needs at an earlier point, and is able to figure out that it doesn't need access to the surrounding scope.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Regarding the argument types in the lambda - I'm curious why adding argument types helps, but the spec has only left me with more questions: https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#lambdas

According to that, the version without types (`(a, b) => ...`) doesn't seem to be legal at all. Do you know what's going on when that syntax is used?

Comment: That's an error in the spec. Probably, someone thought `ParameterWithMemberAttributes` (another error in the spec), which resolves to `(parameterList)` allows for multiple identifiers with no types. The spec is maintained separately from the compilers, so sadly there are some inconsistencies.